# Undefined scope when using client side People Picker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using the following directive, but getting a 'undefined' error why I attempt to console.log or alert the value of $scope.cc

https://github.com/jasonvenema/sharepoint-angular-peoplepicker

Here is the HTML for the field. Does anyone know why this would log as undefined?

```
<sp-people-picker name="CC" id="CC" ng-model="$scope.cc" min-entries="1" max-entries="20" allow-duplicates="false" show-login="false" show-title="true" min-characters="2" app-web-url="$scope.spAppWebUrl" />
```

Comment: ng-model="cc" is what you need

Comment: Duh! Giant typo on my part/not enough sleep! Please create an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: As I wanted to put some more information, so I already did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access model set in scope, you do not need to specify $scope in your views.

You need to update your html to

```
<sp-people-picker name="CC" id="CC" ng-model="cc" min-entries="1" max-entries="20" allow-duplicates="false" show-login="false" show-title="true" min-characters="2" app-web-url="{{spAppWebUrl}}" />
```

Comment: That was it. I took the example as literal and mixed with too much code on the page overlooked it.